# How to send submitted form data to a local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to build a very basic full stack application with React and Node. I'm having trouble getting the front end to send the data to the server. I'm getting `POST http://localhost:4000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)` in my console. What do I need to do to send the data submitted by the user to the server so I can store it in a database?

My react code

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {text: ''}
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/users', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: this.state.text // trying to send this text to the server
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('success writing to server', response)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('error writing to server', err);
            })
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            text: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Name" ref="name" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const port = process.env.port || 4000;
const app = express();

let db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'my_db'
})


app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/users', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body) // undefined
    // I would have thought that req.body.text would work but req.body is undefined
    db.query(`INSERT INTO users (user) VALUES ("${req.body.text}")`, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error inserting into database', err.sqlMessage);
        } else {
            console.log('successful insertion into database', result);
        }
    });
    res.sendStatus(201);
});
app.listen(port, 'localhost');
```

Comment: Are you getting an error ? what are you seeing in the network console for your fetch request ? Can you give us a screenshot of it ?

Comment: Yes I'm getting `POST http://localhost:4000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in your request, you are telling your server that it is going to receive a JSON object.
However, the body that you are sending is `this.state.text` which is the raw value in your input, a string, not a JSON, this is why your server sees it as undefined.

You first need to put it in a JSON, and then stringify it before sending it to your server :

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/users', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify({ textInput: this.state.text })
})
```

Another way around could be to tell the server that it is going to receive raw text :

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/users', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}, //Expects a raw text body
    body: this.state.text
})
```

You can see a more precise explanation of how to use fetch in the following documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

Your Express server seems to be missing body parser middleware. Add this before your route handlers:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Also in general you need to pass the body to `JSON.stringify()` when making a `fetch` request client-side.